# How to remove MOTD segment when no updates/upgrades?

Tags: motd

When I log in to the terminal/via SSH, I see this message, where `x` is a number of updates:

```
x packages can be updated.
x updates are security updates.
```

However, if the number to both is 0, I'd prefer not to see the message.

I've tried modifying the MOTD files but from what I can see I can either allow them to show, or hide them, but nothing conditional. The content of the `90-updates-available` file is:

```
#!/bin/sh

stamp="/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available"

[ ! -r "$stamp" ] || cat "$stamp"
```

...and the contents of `/var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available` is:

```
0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.
```

How can I modify the `90-updates-available` file to prevent showing the message if both the messages start with `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably do something like:

```sh
if [ -r "$stamp" ] 
then
    awk '{c += $1; out = out "\n" $0} END {if (c != 0) print out}' /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available
fi
```

This just takes the sum of the first field and prints the file if the sum is non-zero.

Comment: This works (that I can see!). Would this only work if the *first* number is `0`, or if *both* update numbers are `0`?

Comment: @Ben `awk` operates line-wise, so it sums the first number on both lines. So, for the sum to be zero, both numbers have to be zero (or x and -x, which I hope won't happen).

Comment: I see. Is this written in Bash? If so, can you recommend a source to learn it? Thanks!

Comment: The `if` condition is in shell, yes. The awk part is written in, well, awk. Here's a guide: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change the line:

```
[ ! -r "$stamp" ] || cat "$stamp"
```

to

```
([ ! -r "$stamp" ] || [ -n "$(awk '/^0/{print $1;}' "$stamp")" ]) || cat "$stamp"
```

This will do it.

Comment: I'm following the logic (kinda) but unfortunately this didn't work :(

Comment: Uh o.k. let me test that here I think its not much to change to make it work :)

Comment: If I were to guess, herestrings (`<<<"$stamp"`) don't work with `/bin/sh`. Just `grep "^0" "$stamp"`, or even skipping the grep: `awk '/^0/{print $1;}' "$stamp"`, should be better

Comment: yes you're right just did run this through `shellcheck` and it told me the same. I will edit my answer then :)

Comment: @Ben now this line is working, thanks to muru.

Answer (score 0):

Here'a a variant using `sed` instead of `awk` that suppresses any line that starts with a count of `0`, and joins both regular updates and security updates lines if both have counts:

```
[ ! -r "$stamp" ] || sed -e '/^0 /d' -e 'N; s/\n0 .*//; s/\n/ /' -- "$stamp"
```